# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase` for database and `react-native-camera` that uses `firebase-mlkit`. The problem occured when I installed 'react-native-firebase', now I am getting this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugAidl'.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.2.2,17.2.2]], but resolves to 17.2.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

This is my gradle implementation for libraries:

```
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2"  // Firebase analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```

I checked previous stackoverflow question and tried changing the `firebase-core` and `firebaser-database` version to the same as `firebase-analytics`, but that gave an error on resolving the package path. I tried replacing version with "+" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by restarting the computer and **synchronizing the project in Android Studio**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I solved it with updating versions

Comment: You're welcome, can you share how or at least a link to where you found the solution (that might be helpful for others). Thank you